# Añadir un valor propio y un DataSet a un ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

tengo un problema a la hora de crear un combo box en visual studio.
La estructura del combo box una vez iniciada la aplicación es de la siguiente forma:

[image]

Y el código que lo carga es el siguiente:

> Dim ds As New DataSet

```
    ds = mer.ObtenerResultados()
    cmbMerchant.Properties.DataSource = ds.Tables("TABLA")
    cmbMerchant.Properties.ValueMember = "COD"
    cmbMerchant.Properties.DisplayMember = "NOMBRE"
```

Entonces lo que yo quiero obtener es un valor por defecto que ponga "TODOS" y que se pueda seleccionar (como si fuese una opción más)

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hay varias formas de solucionarlo. La mas sencilla es que insertes una fila en tu tabla en la primera posicion con el campo `Nombre` a `TODOS`. Por cierto..es vb.net no?

Comment: @Pikoh Si, es vb.net. El problema que tenemos es que no podemos insertar una fila en la tabla.

Comment: No en la tabla en la base de datos, si no en la tabla dentro de tu dataset `ds`

Comment: @Pikoh Osea a la hora de recibirlo, ¿no? Y... ¿cómo se haría?

Comment: Te he puesto una respuesta, a ver si te sirve.

Comment: Ahora lo miro y te digo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias formas de solucionarlo. La mas sencilla es que insertes una fila en tu tabla en la primera posición con el campo `Nombre` a `TODOS`. Sería algo asi:

```
Dim dr As DataRow = ds.Tables("TABLA").NewRow()
dr.ItemArray = New Object() {0, "TODOS"}
ds.Tables("TABLA").Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0)
```

Al poner el `ItemArray` ten en cuenta que debes poner todas las columnas que tenga tu tabla en el orden correcto.

Comment: Perfecto, justo lo que necesitaba. Muchisimas gracias.